# animation to start from center of div using css3 only

Tags: css, animation

Okay here is the thing,

I have the animation centered in the middle of the page and it start automatically as soon as the page loads but I want the animation to start from the middle of the page, expanding towards the right size. Not from the top left corner!!
I know it can be done using jquery but I want to use only CSS.

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have 
    http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/9gXNc/

```
#container{
width: 700px;
height:350px;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin:-175px 0 0 -350px;
 }

#intro{
width: 700px;
height:350px;
box-shadow:15px 15px 15px #333;
-webkit-box-shadow:15px 15px 15px #333;/*Safari and Chrome*/
-moz-box-shadow:15px 15px 15px #333;/*Mozilla Firefox*/
border-top: 2px solid #ccc ;
border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
background: #fff;
animation:welcome 2s;
animation-timing-function:linear;
animation-play-state:running;
-webkit-animation:welcome 2s; /*Safari and Chrome*/
-webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
-webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes welcome{
from{ 
width:0px; 
height:0px;
}
to {
width: 700px; 
height:350px;
}
}


/*Safari and Chrome*/
@-webkit-keyframes welcome{
from{ width:0px; height:0px;}
to {width: 700px; height:350px;}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without changing your code too much:

- removed #container - margin, now the container is centered in its top left corner
- added margin-left, margin-top to the animation so the intro would animate left/up as it grew
- added animation fill-mode: forwards to keep the intro in place when the animation was complete.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gXNc/2/)

**CSS**

```
#container {
    width: 700px;
    height:350px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    /*margin:-175px 0 0 -350px;*/
}
#intro {
    position: relative;
    ...
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    /*Safari and Chrome*/
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-play-state:running;
}
```

**Keyframes** (only generic shown here)

```
@keyframes welcome {
    from {
        width:0px;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        height:0px;
    }
    to {
        width: 700px;
        margin-left: -350px;
        margin-top: -175px;
        height:350px;
    }
}
```